# Check performance of variable initializing

Tags: php, variables, laravel-4

I have loop like following and its run for more than 6000 records,

```
foreach ($csv as $value) {
    $research = ResearchData::create(array('company_id' => Input::get('company'), 'date' => Input::get('date')));
}
```

in here i used 2 values company_id and date.
i want to know what is the most good way to use this from follow codes

................1....................

```
$company_id=Input::get('company_id');
$date=Input::get('date');

foreach($csv as value){
   $research=ResearchData::create(array('company_id'=>$company_id,'date'=>$date));
}
```

................2...................

```
foreach ($csv as $value) {
    $research = ResearchData::create(array('company_id' => Input::get('company'), 'date' => Input::get('date')));
}
```

Comment: Number one will be faster but the difference is so minute it's negligible.

Comment: i want to know 1 or 2 is the good way

Comment: I would use the first form, because I often favor variables *for code clarity*; and to reduce the code complexity (and increase the readability) of subsequent expressions.

Comment: can you explain how its possible?.

Comment: The first would be better from the performance perspective

Answer (score 2):

From a performance point of view, number 1 will be faster, but only because `Input::get` will take a tiny little bit longer as it does some checks, an array concatenation and eventually grabs something from an array. This will take a completely negligible amount of time, but option 1 does this once whereas option 2 will do this for every iteration of the loop

From any other point of view (code clarity, documentation etc) it's completely opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a bulk insert. I didn't do a performance check, but I expect a better performance. Check below:

```
$company_id=Input::get('company_id');
$date=Input::get('date');

$data = array_fill(0, count($csv) - 1, ['company_id' => $company_id, 'date' => $date]); // skip the large foreach

ResearchData::insert(array_values($data)); // skip the numeric keys
```

Documentation:

- http://php.net/array_filter
- http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#inserts